# How to show special charecters like "|" in an UIlabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uilabel

In `UIlabel` I can not show the charecter `"|"`, I have tried with

```
[lLebel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat@"%s",[@"your_string" UTF8String]];
```

I am using `"|"` in the place of `"your_string"` but still it is not showing. But when I am using `"%"` it is showing `"%"` (showing right).

I am overloading custom GLTapLabel (https://github.com/laullon/GLTapLabelDemo/blob/master/GLTapLabelDemo) above my label. Is that be the cause to not showing that special character?

Please guide  me the right direction...

Comment: Special characters shouldn't be an issue with `UILabel`s. Is the `|` character available in the font that you have selected for your label's text?

Comment: Simple try with `[lLebel setText:@"your| string"];`.

Comment: just copy | and paste between your string

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am using Helvetica Neue..

Comment: Yes,  dasblinkenlight is correct. also u can simply try this : [lLebel setText:@"|"];, if u only want to print "|" !

Comment: NSS , Rushabh, virusmca, I have tried with the above codes, still it is not showing...

Comment: Are You shure that lLabel exists at that moment? Check what stored in that variable

Comment: Sorry Guys, Please check my edited Question..

Answer (score 0):

```
myLabel.text = @"|";
```

will work just fine!

Comment: Sorry, @Ashley Mills, still it is not showing, I am using the font Helvetica Neue font in the label...

Comment: Sorry Mills, please check my edited question, Your code is running in normal label...

Comment: Without spending too long looking at the code it looks like GLTapLabel is doing something with `symbolCharacterSet` which is causing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it works for me

```
UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 7, 187, 30)];
    label.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

    label.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    [label setText:
     @"|"];

    [self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: @ManabKumarMal first check some other hard coded value like as @"hard code" if you appear "hard code" then your label has been added.if no then check for other mistake also copy my code  i checked in my machine working fine

Comment: Yes @Suman, your code is fine in Normal UILabel, But I am showing it in the GLTapLabel (https://github.com/laullon/GLTapLabelDemo/blob/master/GLTapLabelDemo). I think for that it is Not showing.